# C# Selenium download file that "can harm my computer"

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I try to download a ".cert" file which my Chrome identify to be malicious or has potential to harm my PC. Is there a possibility to disable the following box:
[Popup Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ub7WP.png).
I have searched and tried a ton of possible workarounds or solutions, but none of them worked so far. My Chromeoptions are like that:

```
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData));
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.prompt_for_download", false);
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("disable-popup-blocking", "true");
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.directory_upgrade", true);
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("safebrowsing.enabled", true);
```

I am using the following Nuget pakages:

- Selenium WebDriver Version 3.9.1
- Selenium.Chrome.Webdriver Version 2.37

Best Regards,
Kandey

Comment: Don't use self-signed certificates or add the signer to the trusted root repository.

Comment: This is no option for me, since my application is a testautomation for a VPN Server which generates self signed certificates after each installation, so the signer changes after each setup.

Comment: Are you saying that it's not an option to add a certificate generated from a trusted source (Verisign, GoDaddy etc..) to the site which is generating unrelated self-signed certificates?

Comment: Sorry my bad, I just saw the image. I don't believe this is related to the sites SSL cert.

Comment: Have you tried adding the cert to a .ZIP file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553553/why-does-google-chrome-sometimes-warn-that-a-downloaded-pdf-can-harm-your-comput

Comment: No problem, this is also not possible since the Website provides it only as .cert file, usually when I start my browser from non selenium I can add such file to always download, this property must exist also to be set up for the automation :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works using Selenium.WebDriver 3.11.2 and Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver 2.37.0 along with disabling download protection. The blank .crt is still hosted on my blog so you can test if you like.

```
 ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
 options.AddArgument("--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection");
 options.AddUserProfilePreference("safebrowsing", "enabled");

 using (var driver = new ChromeDriver(ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory), options))
 {
    driver.Url = "https://www.kitson-online.co.uk/test.crt";
 }
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it does not seems to work for me, I don't know why. Maybe because my .cert file is a CA-Certificate but I can not imagine that this is the reason. With your URL and your test.crt it is working, for me it already worked with other Certificates with .p12 I have just issues with this self signed CA Certificate.

Comment: Well all I can say is that if I enable download protection, I get the error your stating. If I remove download protection, it works fine without errors. What version of the Chrome Driver are you using? Try 2.9 from here http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.9/

Comment: Ok it did nothing "better" but what I found out is: If I export the CA via html Button, this Warning occurs, whatever I do. If I export the CA via the Link which is behind that button and do: driver.navigate("URLofCertificate"); it is working without any Warning. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Chrome v.85, webdriver v.3.141

Worked for me:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); 
options.AddUserProfilePreference("safebrowsing", "disabled");
driver = new ChromeDriver(Environment.CurrentDirectory, options);
```